# Chances of getting a specific combination of playing cards.

Tags: probability, gambling

Suppose I have 3 playing cards: 2,3,4

If I were to take 2 cards from an **infinte** deck I will get these unique combinations:

- 2,2
- 2,3
- 2,4
- 3,3
- 3,4
- 4,4

Now to the question. If I wanted to know what the chances are of getting one particular combination (say 2,3) do I need to include the double occurrence (3,2 which I omitted above)? Which would result in a 2/9 chance rather than a 1/9 chance.

Comment: That's up to you!  If I first draw a $2$ and then a $3$, is that the same as first drawing a $3$ and then a $2$?  Typically, people would say that these were the same (so then the probability would be $\frac 29$), but it's your game and you set the rules as you like.

Comment: @lulu This is a game modelled after Blackjack so the first two cards are one _hand_, this means I should go with the 2/9 right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Also, instead of saying you have an *infinite deck*, it is much simpler to say you have three cards, and you're drawing two of them *with replacement* (i.e., you draw one, put it back, then draw another).

Comment: @Théophile Thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: @tkon99 No problem. Just to explain further, the issue with an "infinite deck" is that you have to explain what you mean, and that would become too cumbersome for this problem. For example, is your deck countably or uncountably infinite? How do you construct your deck in such a way as to guarantee equal likelihoods of drawing a $2,3$, or $4$? You might say that there's a list of cards $[2,3,4,2,3,4,\ldots]$ and you choose the $n$th card for some random integer $n$... but how do you choose a random number from $1$ to $\infty$? You can see how this quickly gets complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to determine the chances of getting one particular combination (say 2,3) you DO need to include the double occurrence (3,2).

Let's just look at the probability tree for just $2$ and $3$:

$$All~Cards~~~~~~~~$$$$/|~~~~~~~~$$$$2~~~~~3~~~(1/3)$$$$/|~~~~/|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$$$2~~3~~~~2~~3~~(1/3)~~~~~~~$$ As you can see, at each step, we still have a chance to get the conjugate group of cards. So, if we want to see our chances of getting both a $2$ and $3$ from the infinite deck, we would do $\frac13\cdot\frac13+\frac13\cdot\frac13=\frac29$.

Thus, the probability is $2/9$.

Comment: That is actually so easy to comprehend now, thanks! I feel stupid for not coming up with this myself :D